# Does Cassandra support a percentage replication?

Tags: cassandra

I know Cassandra has a replication factor for the keyspace but I was wondering if Cassandra had the ability to specify a replication percentage. Instead of specifying the number of nodes you want to replicate the data you could specify the percentage of the number of nodes you have.

This is not necessarily a question if I need this but I'm curious if Cassandra has this functionality or if Cassandra could support this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Cassandra use only the replication factor as number nodes -- a percentage does not necessarily makes sense -- what if I choose 35% and I have a 4 nodes cluster? Each node can own a 25% data and so the replication can be either 1 node (25%) or two nodes (50%) but no one match my specification.

Comment: When you specify a replication factor say to 2 nodes out of 4 that means 2 nodes have 100% of the data, correct?

Comment: No, it does not. It means that if you are using equally distributed partitions 1 node over X will have 1/X partitions -- and the data this node owns are replicated by a second node (RF = 2 -- 2 nodes for the same partitioned information). To make it easy, if you have 50 nodes and an equally distributed partitioning each node will own about 2% of data -- and for these 2% information there are N replica's (N = replication factor).